# What is the Latin word for the English word "mean"?

Tags: synonyms

In the English language, we might write the following question:

> ## "what does the word `dog` ***mean***"?

What is the Latin word for "***meaning***"?

By "***meaning***" I mean the "*definition of a spoken or written word*"

I am not looking for the Latin word for:

- a ***meaningful*** painting on canvas
- a spiritual ***meaning*** pertaining to god, souls, ghosts, or deamons.
- a ***mean*** dog
- a ***mean*** spirited teenager
- ***meaning***, as in one's life quest or purpose, contentment, or fulfillment.

How do people say, "the words rock and stone have the same ***meaning***?"

A pair of words are ***homographically*** equivalent if they are spelled the same way, but spelling is not meaning.

A pair of words are ***homophonically*** equivalent if and only if the two words are pronounced the same way, such as "know" and "no".

How do you say that two words have the same meaning?

- The two words are ***Homo-fineic***"?
- The words "stone" and "rock" represent a "***homo-gignesthaic***" pair.
- The words "couch" and "sofa" are ***homo destinares***.
- The words "no" and "know" are not equivalent in meaning. They are not homo signum ficare.

Comment: Are you looking for a verb? "Volo" and "significo" are some equivalent. You can download the Lewis and Short app, even the Scriba.

Comment: @Manuel *Volo* is absolutely not an appropriate translation for 'mean' in the sense of 'signify'. Please actually read the entry instead of just searching for a word.

Comment: @Cairnarvon "Quid sibi vult" is actually a pretty standard way of saying "signify/mean," but you're right that it rarely means this when used alone.

Comment: Not sure why this question got so many down votes. Speak up in the comments, anyone, if you see a problem with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The most common word I've seen for that is *significāre*; I've both heard and used the phrase *quid significat ___?* ("what does ___ mean?") countless times in Latin classes.

The second part of your question has nothing to do with Latin—it's about English words borrowed from Greek—but the standard word for that is "synonymous".

Comment: Well, the answer to "How do you say that two words have the same meaning?" is: *Duo verba idem significant.*